# Load .xml to gridview

Tags: c#, xml, gridview

my problem is that i have to load a .xml file to gridview.

when i click the button to load it in the gridview it shows the datas, but hidden in a +.

in the running program
[image]

but i want to load it directly to the gridview.

```
    private void loadbtnxml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet importierteKonten = new DataSet();
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"C:\Users\as\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Test2\Test2\bin\Debug\XMLFile1.xml");

        XmlElement exelement = doc.DocumentElement;
        if (exelement != null)
        {
            XmlNodeReader nodereader = new XmlNodeReader(exelement);
            importierteKonten.ReadXml(nodereader, XmlReadMode.Auto);

            bdsKonto.DataSource = importierteKonten;
            bdsKonto.ResetBindings(true);
        }
    }
```

here is the XML:
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Konto>
  <Konto Kontonummer="1" Kontoname="Peter Zwegat" Alter="55" Kontostand="5462€" />
  <Konto Kontonummer="2" Kontoname="Günther Griesgram" Alter="39" Kontostand="2334€" />
  <Konto Kontonummer="3" Kontoname="Siegfried Müller" Alter="46" Kontostand="2973€" />
  <Konto Kontonummer="4" Kontoname="Ömer Akyol" Alter="20" Kontostand="3518€" />
  <Konto Kontonummer="5" Kontoname="Darius Tolkmitt" Alter="23" Kontostand="1947€" />
  <Konto Kontonummer="6" Kontoname="Name des Inhabers" Alter="Alter" Kontostand="Kontostand in €" />
  <Konto Kontonummer="7" Kontoname="Name des Inhabers" Alter="Alter" Kontostand="Kontostand in €" />
  <Konto Kontonummer="8" Kontoname="Name des Inhabers" Alter="Alter" Kontostand="Kontostand in €" />
  <Konto Kontonummer="9" Kontoname="Name des Inhabers" Alter="Alter" Kontostand="Kontostand in €" />
</Konto>`

Comment: What do you mean by "hidden in a +". i m not able to see anything a+ in your image

Comment: between kontonummer and konto is a minus where you can hide the datas

Comment: Show your xml file

Comment: i posted the xml file

Comment: is it windows application or asp.net webform application?

Comment: windows application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Steps i have mentioned Here

> 1) I have added a xml file in the application named as
>   **"XMLFile1.xml"** and reading from that xml file to a string.
>
> 2) Convert the xml `string` to a `DataSet` >>> `DataTable`.
>
> 3) Assign the `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` to the `DataTable`
>   available inside the `DataSet`.

Try and let me know if you still face any issues

***Code***

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PopulateGridviewWindowsFormsApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void loadbtnxml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlString = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\My Apps\WinForm Application\PopulateGridviewWindowsFormsApp\PopulateGridviewWindowsFormsApp\XMLFile1.xml");
            DataTable dtKonto = ConvertXmlStringToDatatable(xmlString);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtKonto;
        }

        //Convert a xml string to datatable
        public static DataTable ConvertXmlStringToDatatable(string xmlData)
        {
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(xmlData);
            DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
            theDataSet.ReadXml(sr);
            return theDataSet.Tables[0];
        }
    }
}
```

***Output***

[image]

Hope it solves your problem.

Comment: when i do it like you did the gridview shows the right number of rows, but they are all empty

Comment: yes the output i have given in the screenshot. did u tried that?

Comment: According to your code the xml file is available in this path "C:\Users\as\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Test2\Test2\bin\Debug\XMLFile1.xml" . but for me i created in another path. you always point to your location

Comment: what you have changed?. did you add the method "ConvertXmlStringToDatatable" inside your Form class code? then did you call to that menthod and assign to the datagridview control? before that check  the dataset. is is holding a datatable or it is null? Debug and check it